Jackson Deserialization of Objects Extending Abstract Classes Using Generics
I've seen plenty of examples of how to deal with Jackson deserialization when using abstract classes and generics, but I'm trying to understand why type inference isn't possible in certain cases. Consider the following:
Objects:
public abstract class BaseObject {
    public String someField;
}

public class ConcreteObjectOne extends BaseObject {}

public class ConcreteObjectTwo extends BaseObject {}

Classes deserializing objects:
public abstract class BaseService<T extends BaseObject> {
    public T deserializeObjectFail(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var mapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();

        return mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<T>() {});
    }

    public T deserializeObjectSuccess(String json, TypeReference<T> typeReference) throws JsonProcessingException {
        var mapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();

        return mapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
    }
}

public class ConcreteServiceOne extends BaseService<ConcreteObjectOne> {}

public class ConcreteServiceTwo extends BaseService<ConcreteObjectTwo> {}

Tests:
var serviceOne = new ConcreteServiceOne();
var serviceTwo = new ConcreteServiceTwo();

// These fail with an InvalidDefinitionException
serviceOne.deserializeObject("{\"someField\":\"one\"}");
serviceTwo.deserializeObject("{\"someField\":\"two\"}");

// These succeed
serviceOne.deserializeObjectFixed("{\"someField\":\"one\"}", new TypeReference<>() {});
serviceTwo.deserializeObjectFixed("{\"someField\":\"two\"}", new TypeReference<>() {});

Why does the first example fail while the second succeeds? It seems like the generic type should be known in both cases. The class definitions of ConcreteServiceOne and ConcreteServiceTwo provide the concrete object types that T represents.
So shouldn't new TypeReference<T>() {} be able to make use of the types provided for T by the concrete classes? Why would that fail, while using TypeReference<T> as a parameter provided by the concrete classes work even when the concrete classes are using type inference by passing in new TypeReference<>() {}? It seems like the type of T should be able to be inferred equally in both cases, especially considering the generic type can even be omitted in the second example.

TypeReference only works with actual types. Think about it: if you could construct them for a generic T, why wouldn't Jackson do it for you internally?

But with the class definition class ConcreteServiceOne extends BaseService<ConcreteObjectOne>, isn't that saying that ConcreteObjectOne is the actual type that T represents? That would explain how Jackson knows what to do with TypeReference<T> in deserializeObjectSuccess(). So why can't it figure out what looks to me as the same thing, TypeReference<T>, in deserializeObjectFail() since the actual type is known to be ConcreteObjectOne?

@HotN: "isn't that saying that ConcreteObjectOne is the actual type " Yes, but the code in BaseService doesn't know this. The code in deserializeObjectFail is compiled without knowledge about any subclasses and in the compiled code T is erased to Object.

The whole point of TypeReference is that you create it in a part of the code where you can write out the concrete class as type argument. Then you pass it as an argument to the generic code, just as you do with deserializeObjectFixed.

One alternative solution for you that might be better is to store the TypeReference as a field in BaseService, and pass it in as a constructor parameter from the sub-classes.

Looks like type erasure is what I hadn't wrapped my head around. I think I get it now.

In generics, the compiler ensures your type are safe at compilation phase. After that the compiler removes all type information (keyword: type erasure) and convert the objects into type Object for runtime. Thus, your type is basically Object in runtime (without Jackson's explicit TypeReference, deserialization would fail). use. Jackson API lib says that in order to retain type information at runtime, they have TypeReference.
The topic of generics is quite large, but if you want to look for into type erasure, here's the document from Oracle: Type Erasure
I hope I answered your question.

I think type erasure is where I wasn't thinking about things correctly. I've worked mostly in .NET in the past where type erasure doesn't happen and the base class would always understand what T is. I suppose it's just a part of the learning curve of switching between languages and this one caught me.
